# How to draw svg path for ring using css?

Tags: css

I want to draw a ring in an svg using css.

I have the path I want using a polygon, however I want the same using a ring:

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0, 6vh 0, 6vh 61vh, 44vh 61vh, 44vh 6vh, 6vh 6vh);
```

Comment: can you be more clear? probably share a screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

### Solved

Trick is to use four arcs and define the intersection to be used as clip path poly

Like below:

```
clip-path: path(
    "m 10 0 a 10 10 0 0 1 0 20 m 0 -2 a 0.8 0.8 0 0 0 0 -16 
     m 0 -2 a 10 10 0 0 0 0 20 m 0 -2 a 0.8 0.8 0 0 1 0 -16"
);
/* Note for 20x20 :: performing scaling if required */
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am not sure if you can draw a circle in CSS using SVG functions but a simple example in SVG would be

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Or with just pure CSS

```
 <div style="width: 80px;height:80px;background-color: red; border-radius: 50px">
```

Comment: No, I just want clip-path

Comment: I went through it